# I need to toggle between an X button and hamburger menu with Bootstrap. I'm using React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap and want to toggle between the famous X icon and hamburger menu. I don't know if I can actually change the 3 lines of the menu since it's by default, but these 2 icons presently overlap each other.

So there are 2 questions here:

1. How can I toggle these two icons?
2. When the menu is clicked, it should have a complete white background (right now it doesn't completely cover the screen in white)

Sorry I don't have a sandbox example for you right now.

Thanks for your input!

```
/*JSX code*/
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationBarStyled } from './style';
import { Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
//IMAGES
import logo from '../../images/adyslogo.png';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';
import { GrCart } from 'react-icons/gr';
import CloseButton from '../../images/closebutton.svg';


const NavigationBar = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationBarStyled>
            <Navbar expand='sm' fixed='top'>
                <Navbar.Brand href='/'><Image src={logo} className='logo'/></Navbar.Brand>
                <div className='close-button'>
                <button type="button" className="x-closebutton" aria-label="Close">
                    <img src={CloseButton} className='x-button' alt="close configuration" draggable="false" />
                </button>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='basic-navbar-nav' className='hamburger-menu'/>
                </div>

                <Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
                    <Nav className='mr-auto'>
                        <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href='/' className="middle-menu">HOME</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href='/about' className="middle-menu">ABOUT</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href='/menu'  className="middle-menu">MENU</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href='/gallery'  className="middle-menu">GALLERY</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href='/contact'  className="middle-menu">CONTACT</Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav className='ml-auto'>
                        <Nav.Item><Nav.Link href='/cart'><GrCart size='25px' className='cart'/></Nav.Link></Nav.Item>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>                 
            </Navbar>
        </NavigationBarStyled>
    )
}

export default NavigationBar;


/*CSS*/
import styled from 'styled-components';


export const NavigationBarStyled = styled.nav`
    .navbar {
        background-color: #FFF;
        height: 80px;
    }

    .navbar-brand, .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        color: #273746 ;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 600;

        &:hover {
            color: rgb(255, 20, 147);
        }
    }

    .logo {
        max-height: 60px;
        max-width: 60px;
    }

    .middle-menu {
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .cart {
        margin-right: 50px;
        
    }

    .close-button {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    .x-closebutton {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        border: none;
        background-color: #fff; 
        margin-right: -54px;

    }
   
    .x-button {
        display: flex;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hamburger-menu {
        border: none;
        color: #000;
    }

    .mr-auto {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: white;
        min-width: 100vw;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

`;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually rather easy to toggle state but, keep in mind you won't have the graceful height calculation which comes with Bootstrap.

I'll comment out what doesn't seem important to this answer...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
//import { Link } from "gatsby";
//import Image from "./image";
import "../../scss/molecules/_topnav.scss";

//const helpers = require("../../helpers");

class Nav extends Component {
    state = { collapse: true };

    /*
    componentDidMount() {
        helpers.useIntersect(".navbar-collapse", "navbar-collapsed");
    }
    */

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.brandLogo = this.props.brandLogo;
        this.listItems = this.props.pages
            //.sort((a, b) => (a.node.navigationOrder || 100) - (b.node.navigationOrder || 100))
            .map((page) => page.node.slug && page.node.pageName && !page.node.hideInNavigation && (
            <li className="nav-item" key={page.node.id}>
                <Link to={`${page.node.slug}`} className="nav-link" title={page.node.pageName}>{page.node.pageName}</Link>
            </li>)
       );
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <>
              <nav className={[
                  "navbar", 
                  "navbar-expand-lg", 
                  "navbar-light", 
                  "fixed-top", 
                  this.state.collapse ? "" : "active"].join(" ")}
              >
                  <a className="navbar-brand" href="/"><Image fluid={this.brandLogo} /></a>
                  <button 
                      className="navbar-toggler"
                      type="button"
                      data-toggle="collapse"
                      data-target="#topnav"
                      aria-controls="topnav"
                      aria-expanded={!this.state.collapse}
                      aria-label="Toggle navigation" onClick={() => {
                          this.setState({ collapse: !this.state.collapse });
                      }
                  }>
                      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>
                  <div
                      className={[
                          "collapse",
                          "navbar-collapse",
                          "fade",
                          !this.state.collapse ? "show" : "",
                      ].join(" ")} id="topnav">
                      <ul className="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">{this.listItems}</ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Nav;
```

SCSS solution to cover state and mobile -vs- desktop navigation
A simple toggle between `display` "none" and "block". You can transition transforms to counter the missing height calculation.
We'll use the proper `content` characters to cover the icons.
It's a bit too much but I'll leave this file complete.

```
@import "../variables";
@import "../functions";

@import "../vendor/bootstrap/functions";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/variables";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/mixins";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/transitions";

.navbar {
    &.navbar-light {
        transition: all ease 0.2s;

        .navbar-brand {
            transition: all ease 0.2s;

            .image {
                height: auto;
                width: rem-value(142);
            }
        }

        .nav-item {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
        }

        .nav-link {
            font-family: $font-family-monospace;
            font-size: rem-value(20);
        }

        @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
            .navbar-collapse {
                &:not(.show) {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }

            .nav-item {
                margin: auto 1rem;
            }
        }

        @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
            .nav-item {
                &:last-child {
                    .nav-link {
                        background-color: $primary;
                        border-radius: rem-value(3);
                        color: $white;
                        margin-left: 1.5rem;

                        &:hover,
                        &:active,
                        &:focus {
                            background-color: $brand-primary-headings;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @include media-breakpoint-down(md) {
            background-color: $white;
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px $gray-300;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;

            .navbar-brand {
                transform: scale(0.65);
                transform-origin: left;
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 0;
            }

            .navbar-collapse {
                &.collapse {
                    background: white;
                    margin: 0 -1rem;
                    height: 0;
                    transform: scale(0);
                    transform-origin: top center;
                    transition: all ease 0.5s;
                    padding: 1rem;
                    position: relative;

                    &.show {
                        height: calc(100vh - 80px);
                        transform: scale(1);
                    }
                }
            }

            .navbar-toggler {
                &[aria-expanded="true"] {
                    .navbar-toggler-icon {
                        background-image: none;
                        position: relative;

                        &:before {
                            content: "\00d7";
                            font-family: sans-serif;
                            font-size: rem-value(40);
                            line-height: 0.8;
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            left: 0;
                            height: 100%;
                            width: 100%;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            .nav-item {
                border-bottom: 1px solid $gray-300;
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;

                &:before {
                    content: "\203A";
                    line-height: 1.2;
                    font-size: rem-value(30);
                    color: $brand-primary-headings;
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0.5rem;
                    width: rem-value(40);
                    height: rem-value(40);
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }

            .nav-link {
                line-height: 1.8;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @at-root .scrolled & {
            background-color: $white;
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px $gray-300;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;

            .navbar-brand {
                transform: scale(0.65);
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example can be seen at devlab.career

Hopefully with this example you can implement this too.

Comment: ok that was great txs :) have you ever tried converting the 3 lines in the hamburger menu into an X while using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, but by the question alone I can tell you didn't pick that up. See the `content: '\00d7'` or [here](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/multiplication-sign/). Depending on the font-family you can make it a bit more appealing. Or go custom font style like font-awesome or icomoon or fontello or whatever. Or ... do you mean [animated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIyVTjJAkLw) ...? Also tried that but it's far more tricky.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to make it animated. In Bootstrap the hamburger menu both opens and closes when clicked, so the goal is to convert it to an X when clicked.